# How can I assign a texture image to mutiple faces created when extrude tool was used

Tags: edit-mode

I thought that I asked this same question some time ago but entering the title I did not find any similar question so firstly my apologies if in fact I did ask this before and please reply with a link.
I have create a simple building and created the roof and eaves (roof overhang) using the extrude tool. Now I wish to apply a texture image but cannot select all the 'faces' as a collection to apply the material to and so feel that perhaps I need to 'join' all the meshes into a single mesh but cannot work out how to do that in edit mode.
Here is my model showing what I mean.
Thanks

Here is the blender file
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand what you mean, for example what do you mean by "select all the faces as a collection"? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: All that I want to do is to apply a material (image texture) to the entire roof but the way it currently is I cannot find a way to apply the texture image to the entire roof only the various faces shown in edit mode. The entire 'model' seems to be one mesh at this time and so I cannot select the roof separately from the entire model in object mode hence the reason I am trying to apply the material via edit mode. Maybe the easiest method is to ADD a mesh PLANE to each side of the roof and apply the texture image material to those mesh planes?

Comment: Thanks. I have just uploaded the blender file. I tried selecting every edge around the periphery of the top of the roof and then press J but gave a 'invalid order' error.

Comment: Sorry I meant select all the vertices around the rood and separate with V (rip), it will make the roof a separate mesh (you can separate as new object with P), but actually you could give another material to the roof even if it's the same mesh, and even if it's the same object

Comment: Since the roof is already part of the same mesh you can't join it! Select one of the faces on the roof and hit Ctrl-L to select the rest. You can then add and assign your roof material to the selected faces

Comment: Thanks moonboots.      I could not get what you described to work but after watching a couple of pertinent youtube tutorials I manage to do it.      But can't remember all the steps.        I selected all the faces for the top of the roof and then pressed Y (which seems to separate all the selected faces) and then I was able to drag all the top faces away. Now that's where I forget what I did next to join all the faces together which is annoying.

Comment: Thanks John. Pressing L selected every face which I don't want.    What I am trying to do is to add a texture image material to the entire roof but with all those faces (seen in edit mode) and pressing ctrl E mark seam then press u twice and select uv editing I then get every face displayed and have to apply the material to every face separately instead of being able to apply it once to the entire side of the roof. I hope I described my 'problem' enough for you to understand.

Comment: Not really. If you want every face of the roof selected use @Chris answer which is the same as my comment. (Ctrl-L or just 'L' will both work with one face of the roof selected in this case.) There's no need to seperate parts first. Just mark a seam round the lower edge of the roof, one up each corner, U to unwrap and you have your UV ready to apply the roof material.

Answer (score 0):

As John wrote, you can select one face of the roof, then "select linked all" and then assign this to a material like this:

[image]

Comment: Had to go out to shop otherwise I'd have done an answer! You can also select both large faces and use Ctrl-numpad+ a few times to extend the selection.

Comment: Thanks Chris and John. I have no problems with either of your 'solutions' HOWEVER I still cannot unwrap my texture image (material) to enclose the WHOLE area of the top of the roof to 'assign', I can add a new material using a color (material) is easy.  How do I unwrap so that I can apply my TEXTURE IMAGE to the entire TOP of the roof (all faces on the top?  I will now edit my initial question to include a screen shot of the UV-editing screen to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Hey guys I think I have solved it. When applying a texture image I always mark creases and then press u twice to UNWRAP. In this case that seems to be incorrect.           What I did was I selected all the FACES on the top of ONE HALF of the roof, then assigned my texture image and then went to the UV editor (without unwrapping) and rotated (as required) and scaled (as required), returned to Layout mode and the texture image shows on that half of the roof. Is that correct what I did? Well it seems to work. If so should I do an 'answer your question'?

Comment: yeah you could, but maybe you should then also modify your question, because you didn't wrote of that problem with unwrapping...

Comment: Yes I agree.  I presumed incorrectly that I needed to 'join' all the faces before I could successfully assign the texture image.